# Elasticsearch - Fields exist or not for a give filter

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I want to write a query where i want to check if 1 or more fields exist in ES for a given filter. I want to get which of the 1 or more fields exist for the filter and which ones dont.

Can the exists query help with it? Currently what i have is -

```
{   "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "mykey": "my_val02"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "field_key1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }   } }
```

But this seems to filter documents which have the field_key1.

I want a something where i can determine whether-
field_key1 exists in filter "mykey:myvalue1"
field_key2 exists in filter "mykey:myvalue1"
field_key3 does not exist in filter "mykey:myvalue1"

Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, stick the exists queries inside must_not clause like

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "mykey":"my_val02"
               }
            },
            {
               "must_not":{
                  "exists":{
                     "field":"field_key1"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

This will return all docs that have my_val02 and field_key1 doesn't exist. To add other clauses, add outer should clause and copy the same as above inside as many times as you need